# What is the difference between Enum and MaterialEnum?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity shaders, sometimes you can see either syntax:

> [Enum(Off,0,Front,1,Back,2)] _Cull ("Cull", Int) = 2

> [MaterialEnum(Off,0,Front,1,Back,2)] _Cull ("Cull", Int) = 2

[In the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyDrawer.html) they only talk about `Enum`.

The results are exactly the same Inspector but I imagine they do differ somehow...

**Question:**

What's the difference between `Enum` and `MaterialEnum` keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: **They are indeed just synonyms!**

---

Looking into the [`MaterialPropertyDrawer` source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/Inspector/MaterialPropertyDrawer.cs) the according drawer class there actually it is called [`MaterialEnumDrawer`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Editor/Mono/Inspector/MaterialPropertyDrawer.cs#L515) internally.

But in [`GetShaderPropertyDrawer`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Editor/Mono/Inspector/MaterialPropertyDrawer.cs#L123) when they search for a drawer implementation for a given attribute [they do](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Editor/Mono/Inspector/MaterialPropertyDrawer.cs#L139)

```c#
...

// When you write [Foo] in shader, get Foo, FooDrawer, MaterialFooDrawer,
// FooDecorator or MaterialFooDecorator class;
// "kind of" similar to how C# does attributes.

if (klass.Name == className ||
    klass.Name == className + "Drawer" ||
    klass.Name == "Material" + className + "Drawer" ||
    klass.Name == className + "Decorator" ||
    klass.Name == "Material" + className + "Decorator")
{

...
```

so as you can see it basically doesn't matter if you write it with or without `Material` they are basically treated as synonyms:

- for `[Enum]` you get `Enum`, `EnumDrawer`, **`MaterialEnumDrawer`**, `EnumDecorator` or `MaterialEnumDecorator`
- for `[MaterialEnum]` you get `MaterialEnum`, **`MaterialEnumDrawer`**, `MaterialMaterialEnumDrawer`, `MaterialEnumDecorator` or `MaterialMaterialEnumDecorator`

=> The one you are actually looking for **[`MaterialEnumDrawer`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Editor/Mono/Inspector/MaterialPropertyDrawer.cs#L515)** is found by both versions.

So basically you can write it as one of the following

```
Enum
MaterialEnum
MaterialEnumDrawer
```

---

**Fazit:** Use `[Enum]`!

- it's shorter ;)
- others can find it in the API

Comment: Amazing, I grep-ed builtin shaders but haven't thought about sources, thanks :)